# How do I iterate over the coordinates of a line between two coordinates?

Tags: rust

I have a struct called `Point` with `x` and `y` coordinates and a tuple struct called `Line` which has two `Points`. I want to have a method on the `Point` struct which returns an iterator of all the points between those two points in that struct, including the points themselves. I already have some checks for if it isn't horizontal or vertical, so you can just panic there. What's the idiomatic way to do this? Is there a trait that I should implement for the `iter` method? I just can't find out how to do this with a range nor by creating my own iterator struct.

I had a load of other, more specific problems, but I don't want to mention them because I think they probably aren't even on the correct track and if I solved it the idiomatic way, I probably won't need it anyway and it would be a waste of time. This is intentionally quite a broad question.

Edit 2: It's for Battleships. I have a HashSet of all hit targets, I need to check if a ship is sunk, among other things.

Edit 1: And just my code which doesn't work just in case:

````rust
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl Point {
    fn new(x: u8, y: u8) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
}

struct Line(Point, Point);

impl Line {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
        if self.0.x == self.1.x {
            to_iter_u8(self.0.y, self.1.y).map(|y| Point::new(self.0.x, y))
        } else if self.0.y == self.1.y {
            to_iter_u8(self.0.x, self.1.x).map(|x| Point::new(x, self.0.y))
        } else {
            panic!("Points must be horizontal or vertical to each other");
        }
    }
}

fn to_iter_u8(a: u8, b: u8) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    if a > b {
        b..=a
    } else {
        a..=b
    }
}
```
````

Comment: "All points" meaning, what? Integer pixel values? Increments of some length? Mathematically speaking there is an infinite number of points on a line of any length.

Comment: @tadman I should have specified but why ask? Every number a computer can represent is some finite value. It really doesn't matter because it's not relevant to the implementation. You can just scale it up or down. But I chose a u8 because that's the range I need.

Comment: This is how an iterator is created: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/iter.html maybe you show what you already have, so we can help more on the problem

Comment: @ihatenullptrs They asked because it's an important and valid question. For example, if you are using floats then would you really want an iterator of every single possible set of floating point coordinates that may differ by only the epsilon? Your question is underspecified in this regard, and SO is not fond of making guesses regarding information that hasn't been provided to us.

Comment: It can represent extremely precise "finite" values, so the only limit to precision here is your patience. Remember, lines are not only used for things like rasterizing pixels, but also ray tracing, where way more precision is required. I had no idea if this was step one of a [ray marching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_marching) implementation.

Comment: "a method on the Point struct which returns an iterator of all the points between those two points"...between what two points? Do you mean on the `Line` struct, or are you saying the function should take another `Point` as an argument.

Comment: It seems like there may be 2 parts to this question: 1) how do I get a list of all points on a line using linear algebra, 2) how do I implement this in code. The former isn't really an SO question

Comment: @Codebling No, I already said number 1, I know how to do number 2. I have two points, I need all the points between those two, assuming that it's not diagonal and it's an integer.

Comment: @Codebling Yes, the 2 points in the line struct.

Comment: @cdhowie Why does it matter? It's quite obvious it's an integer. And if it were a float, it's not at all relevant to the question. Every float is just a composition of integers since a finite value and you can just scale it up or down. Unless it somehow is relevant?

Comment: @tadman Well it doesn't matter if it's a float or not. It wouldn't matter if it was an i8 in steps of 2 either. In case you want to know, it's for Battleships. I just need every point in the ship.

Comment: Points on a grid is a lot easier to implement. Give it a starting `x,y` coordinate, a direction (`enum`?), and a length. This way you can't end up with invalid "diagonal" lines.

Comment: @ihatenullptrs so just to be clear, are we only talking about 45° diagonal lines (the hypotenuse of an isosceles right angle triangle)? Before if not (and since you specified that we're talking about integer coordinates), it's likely there won't be any points on the line. You specifically mentioned "assuming that it's not diagonal" so this is confusing.

Comment: Please also note that your replies to comments have a hostile tone, which tends to frustrate people and make them less likely to help you. For a new user asking a (poor) first question, you may want to be especially mindful of your tone when replying to people who are only trying to help (instead, you appear to be vaguely insinuating that they are dumb, with statements like "it's quite obvious")

Comment: @Codebling Ok sorry for the tone but it's very hard to say something and always have it come across correctly. I was just trying to say whether it's an int or not is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Codebling No, it's only horizontal or vertical lines, becuase ships in battleships can only be placed like that. It's confusing because the panic message was wrong and said horizontal and diagonal instead of horizontal and vertical. By diagonal I mean anything that is not horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iter` function fails to compile for a few reasons.

First, you've declared the type of `Iterator::Iter` to be `u8`, but the function is actually trying to return an iterator of `Point` values.  This is easily solved by changing the declared return type to match.

Second, you accept `self` by reference but you don't indicate that the returned `Iterator` captures the lifetime of the reference.  There's two ways to fix this:

1. Indicate the captured lifetime (`impl Iterator<Item = Point> + '_`).
2. Make `Point` implement `Copy` and take `self` by value.
3. Extract the `x` or `y` value in `iter` before returning the iterator.

The second option is probably better since the type is very small, and it should probably implement `Copy` anyway.  You'll have to make your closures `move` in order to copy `self` into them.

Up to this point, the fixed code looks like this (code not changed has been omitted):

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl Line {
    fn iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point> {
        if self.0.x == self.1.x {
            to_iter_u8(self.0.y, self.1.y).map(move |y| Point::new(self.0.x, y))
        } else if self.0.y == self.1.y {
            to_iter_u8(self.0.x, self.1.x).map(move |x| Point::new(x, self.0.y))
        } else {
            panic!("Points must be horizontal or diagonal");
        }
    }
}
```

The last problem is that `impl Iterator` doesn't mean "any type implementing `Iterator`," it means "one type implementing `Iterator` inferred from the function body."  The two returning conditionals both return a value implementing `Iterator`, but the closure passed to `map` in both cases is of a different type (they have to be different types to behave differently), and the closure's type is part of the iterator's type.  Therefore, the two conditional blocks do not return the same type, and compilation fails.

There's a few ways this problem can be solved.

The easiest (but least efficient) option would be to return a `Box<dyn Iterator>`.  This requires a heap allocation to hold the iterator and dynamic dispatch to iterate over the items, but allows you to return iterators of different types.

```
impl Line {
    fn iter(self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Point>> {
        if self.0.x == self.1.x {
            Box::new(to_iter_u8(self.0.y, self.1.y).map(move |y| Point::new(self.0.x, y)))
        } else if self.0.y == self.1.y {
            Box::new(to_iter_u8(self.0.x, self.1.x).map(move |x| Point::new(x, self.0.y)))
        } else {
            panic!("Points must be horizontal or diagonal");
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use the [`either` crate](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/index.html), which provides an enum type `Either` with two variants (Left and Right), each of which can hold a different type.  This type implements many traits (including `Iterator`) as long as both the left and right types do.

```
impl Line {
    fn iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point> {
        if self.0.x == self.1.x {
            Either::Left(to_iter_u8(self.0.y, self.1.y).map(move |y| Point::new(self.0.x, y)))
        } else if self.0.y == self.1.y {
            Either::Right(to_iter_u8(self.0.x, self.1.x).map(move |x| Point::new(x, self.0.y)))
        } else {
            panic!("Points must be horizontal or diagonal");
        }
    }
}
```

The last option would be to roll your own iterator type.   In many cases this can be more efficient than using `Either`, but in this particular case, the generated code will be very similar and have about the same performance characteristics: a custom iterator is going to require a conditional to handle vertical vs. horizontal iteration, just as `Either` requires a conditional to determine if the wrapped iterator is the left or right type.

Comment: I managed to do the Box pointer, dyn and lifetime with some help for the compiler on my own, (which I should have said but I didn't because it didn't feel like a real answer), but I wouldn't have thought of cloning it.

Comment: How can I ask better questions next time?